# How do I telnet to a box and read/write username/password from dictionary; and recognize certain prompts

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, telnet

How do I telnet to a box and have it echo what I typed in to verify
I'm truly logged in?????????

```
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet()
host = "10.59.50.171"
newline = "\n"
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(host, '23')
telnet.read_until("Username: ".encode())
telnet.write(username)
telnet.read_until("Password: ")
telnet.write(password)

user_acct = {'ADMIN':'PASSWORD','READONLY':'PASSWORD'}

if username in user_acct and password == user_acct[username]: 
    print('Correct Login')
else:
    print('Invalid Login... Please Try Again')
```

Comment: 1st prompt = Username:
2nd prompt = Password:
3rd prompt = TA5000>, The TA5000 is foo
4th prompt = TA5000#, again the TA5000 is foo
5th prompt = TA5000(config)#, once again the TA5000 is foo

Comment: I have not created a variable for TA5000 yet

Comment: Try [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html). Use the `before` attribute to see what was printed before the prompt.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what pexpect is and I don't know how to use the before. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to use the [latest pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) to control a telnet session:

```
from pexpect import fdpexpect
import pexpect
import select
import socket

class SocketSpawn(fdpexpect.fdspawn):
    def read_nonblocking(self, size=1, timeout=-1):
        if timeout == -1:
            timeout = self.timeout
        rlist = [self.child_fd]
        wlist = []
        xlist = []
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(rlist, wlist, xlist, timeout)
        if self.child_fd not in rlist:
            raise pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT('Timeout exceeded.')
        return super(fdpexpect.fdspawn, self).read_nonblocking(size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    host = '10.59.50.171'
    port = 23
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    session = SocketSpawn(s, timeout=10)
    session.expect_exact('Username: ')
    print session.before
    session.write("%s\n" % username)
    session.expect_exact('Password: ')
    print session.before
    session.write("%s\n" % password)
    try:
        session.expect_exact(pexpect.EOF)
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        pass
    print session.before
```

You will need the `SocketSpawn` class to fix a defect that was introduced in the latest versions of `pexpect`. However, this should also work with older versions of `pexpect`.